# How do I use Pandas to_string to write a csv file with different precisions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame in the format:

```
3  -1305.55 -1.638500e+01 -689.773  4.020000e-02
13  2301.26  6.385300e+11 -189.170  1.040270e+06
```

I was unable to use the format:

```
df.to_string(fn, formatters=[" %0.2f ", " %0.5e ", " %0.2f ", " %0.5e"])
```

I got:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: The formatters should be callable functions.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenter mentioned, `formatters` must be a list or dictionary of callables. This is easily accomplished with Python's new-style formatting.

```
print(df.to_string(
    formatters=['{:0.2f}'.format, '{:0.5e}'.format, '{:0.2f}'.format, '{:0.5e}'.format]))
```

```
          0            1       2           3
3  -1305.55 -1.63850e+01 -689.77 4.02000e-02
13  2301.26  6.38530e+11 -189.17 1.04027e+06
```

Comment: none of my numbers came out in exponential format. for example "-1.63850e+01" came out as "-16.3850"

Comment: If someone encounters the error in my comment above, that means the data frame was an object not floats. you also need `df=df.transform(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`